# Restrict Users from USER Pages/Create a Second Timeline in PHPFox

Tags: phpfox

I want to preface this with the following: I'm new to PHPFox, and it isn't my site I'm managing. I have a friend who is working on a social media project that has tasked me with helping him.

What I'm looking to do is create a parallel timeline for users. Instead of just one timeline, we want to create a separate one, for other topics. This sounds much like a user page, right?

Here's the issue: I have to restrict users who don't have permissions to view this page. When going through User Group settings, though, there's no option I can see to hide individual user pages.

I need some way to make a second timeline that only some users can see. How can I do this? I have serverside access if I need to modify individual files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict user by assigning the roles to user including this line of code in start of controller `process()` to restrict user as only Admin

```
Phpfox::isUser(true);
Phpfox::isAdmin(true);
```